# Maximum length of libusb bulk transfer

Tags: linux, libusb

Is there a maximum length of bulk transfers when using libusb in Linux?

For example can you pass any positive value as the length parameter of the function `libusb_fill_bulk_transfer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it is the max positive value of an `int` on the target system.  The length parameter is ultimately used to initialize the length member of the transfer structure (see libusb.h, relative and abbreviated code pasted below).

In reality, I imagine the exact number is device dependent and/or application specific.  I have seen discussions that claim to have issues with larger packet sizes (for example: [LibUSB driver issues: timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139854/libusb-driver-issues-timeout)).

**libusb_fill_bulk_transfer:**

```
static inline void libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(
    struct libusb_transfer *transfer,
    libusb_device_handle *dev_handle, 
    unsigned char endpoint,
    unsigned char *buffer, 
    int length, libusb_transfer_cb_fn callback,
    void *user_data, 
    unsigned int timeout)
{
            /* NOTE: Only relevant code is pasted here.  For complete code see official libusb.h file included with your distribution.  */
    transfer->length = length;
}
```

**libusb_transfer:**

```
struct libusb_transfer 
{
    /* NOTE: Only relevant code is pasted here.  For complete code see official libusb.h file included with your distribution.  */

    /** Length of the data buffer */
    int length;
};
```